# Given $\cos(a) +\cos(b) = 1$, prove that $1 - s^2 - t^2 - 3s^2t^2 = 0$, where $s = \tan(a/2)$ and $t = \tan(b/2)$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $\cos(a) + \cos(b) = 1$, prove that $1 - s^2 - t^2 - 3s^2t^2 = 0$, where $s  = \tan(a/2)$ and $t  = \tan(b/2)$.

I have tried using the identity $\cos(a) = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$. but manipulating this seems to have got me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} +\frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}=1$

$1+s^2-t^2-s^2t^2+1+t^2-s^2-s^2t^2=1+s^2+t^2+s^2t^2$

$\Rightarrow 1-s^2-t^2-3s^2t^2=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}+\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=1$$

$$\iff\dfrac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}=1-\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

$$\iff(1-s^2)(1+t^2)=2t^2(1+s^2)$$

Comment: thanks for the help, but wouldn't it be $2t^2(1+s^2)$ on the final line

Comment: @El_Mathematica, Thanks, rectified

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:
$$\cos a=2\cos^2 \frac a2-1; \\
\cos^2 \frac a2=\frac 1{1+\tan^2 \frac a2}=\frac1{1+s^2}\\
\cos a+\cos b=2\cos ^2 \frac a2+2\cos^2 \frac b2-2=\\
\frac2{1+s^2}+\frac2{1+t^2}-2=1.$$
I leave to you to simplify it.